# Exchanged colors of opaque border on gradient background

Tags: html, css, background, gradient, rgba

I try to apply an opaque border to a div with a gradient background. However, the result is rather unexpected to me since the top and bottom colors seem to become exchanged.

html:

```
<div>
    Test
</div>
```

css:

```
div {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , blue, red);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top , blue, red);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dULyt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Using **`background-size`** property set to something bigger than **100%** (e.g. **110%**)

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/R2W74/)

```
div{
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , blue, red);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top , blue, red);
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    background-size:110%;
}
```

---

It's not 'exchanging' or anything. The background is simply repeating itself.
You have to add **`no-repeat`** to your `background` property.

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/k_rma/gTCfh/)

```
div {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , blue, red) no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top , blue, red) no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Comment: I see. However, with this solution the border is no more opaque over the `background` of the `div`, but rather opaque over the `body`. Unfortunately, this is not exactly what I had in mind. Is there a way to get my intended result? Maybe by giving the `gradient` a greater `height` by `2px` or so?

Comment: Borders are rendered outside the `div` and not within it.

Comment: Strange then that without the `no-repeat` the border is rendered inside the `div`. Or is the background outside the `div` in that case? In any case, that is the effect I would like to have, but without the exchanged colors.

Comment: Strange indeed. As a workaround, you could use `background-size`. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel
Here what makes it more easier for you to make an opaque border.
Using box-shadow property with 0 offset can full-fill your requirement.

here is the code that may help you to get the desired result.

```css
div {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , blue, red) no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top , blue, red) no-repeat;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
}
```

```html
<div>
  Test
</div>
```

Looking forward to your reply brother.